# How to remove unintentional distortion from geometry?

Tags: rendering, geometry

Maybe this question already has an answer, but I'm uncertain of how to ask this question in a good way, so here we go.

My geometry seen below is rendered quite funny with a distortion that seems to be added across the geometry that can't be removed by replacing old vertices with new ones. There are no vertices duplicates in the mesh and I have reset the normals (funny thing the distortion moves around whenever I reset normals).

Is there any way to remove this distortion that I have missed? I am using Blender 2.83.

[image: Image showing the distortion that runs across my geometry.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this turned out to be much easier than I anticipated. It is all about flipped normals where some faces have their normal vectors pointing inside the mesh instead of outside. It can be shown in Edit mode (face mode) with face dots and face orientation enabled in the Overlays like this:

[image: Image of the geometry with its face orientation enabled]

It turns out all you need to do is select all the faces on the mesh and recalculate the normals (you want blue facing outward; blue is facing toward you and red is facing away from you). Another way to see the direction of the face normals (instead of turning on Face Orientation) is by showing their vectors:

[image]

Big thanks to Chris Kohl (ckhol_art) over at https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-remove-unintentional-distortion-from-geometry/1241104/3 for providing me with this fantastic answer and explanation.

Comment: A *much* faster way to fix this is, while editing, select all vertices of the problematic object ('select all' / `A` will often work; in your case you might want to select only the vertices of a single body-panel), then Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside (`Shift`+`N`).